# Pandas data frame, to_csv creating duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my current code

```
data = pd.read_csv('file', sep='\t', header=[2])
ndf = pd.DataFrame(data=nd)
new_data = pd.concat([data, ndf])
new_data.to_csv('file', sep='\t', index=False, mode='a', header=False)
```

So the file I am reading has 3 rows of headers, the headers in the first 2 rows are not used but I need to keep them there.
The headers in row 3 are the same as the headers in ndf, when I concat data and ndf the new_data dataframe is correctly aligned. So there's no problem there.

The problem comes when I try to write the new_data back to the original file with append mode. Every row of data that was in the original file is duplicated. This happens each time.

I have tried adding drop_duplicates `new_data = pd.concat([data, ndf]).drop_duplicates(subset='item_sku', keep=False)`
But this still leaves me with 2 of each row each time I write back to file.

I also tried reading the file with multiple header rows: `header=[0, 1, 2]`
But this makes the concat fail, I'm guessing because it's I haven't told the concat function which row of headers to align with. I think passing keys= would work but I'm not understanding the documentation very well.

EDIT-
This is an example of the file I am reading

```
load  v1.0            74b          FlatFile
ver   raid            week         month    
Dept  Date            Sales        IsHoliday
1     2010-02-05      24924.50     False
```

This would be the data I am trying to append

```
Dept  Date            Sales        IsHoliday
3     2010-07-05      6743.50      False
```

And this is the output I am getting

```
load  v1.0            74b          FlatFile
ver   raid            week         month    
Dept  Date            Sales        IsHoliday
1     2010-02-05      24924.50     False
1     2010-02-05      24924.50     False
3     2010-07-05      6743.50      False
```

Comment: You're duplicating it. file.csvhas column "two" with value 1,2,3. You read it onto df.
df now has two: 1,2,3. You append ndf with column "two" and value 4,5 and 6. new_data is two: 1,2,3,4,5,6. You take that new_data and append it to file.csv, which originally had 1,2,3. Now it has column two: 1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6. Besides, if it has more columns you are adding NaNs to those columns, as you only read one column for df.

Comment: I gathered as much. How would you go about fixing the duplication?

Comment: Don't append, just re-write the file. You're gonna lose the columns you're not reading though. So maybe best to create a separate file? 
We need more context and optimally some example data

Comment: The output file is not duplicating my header rows [0, 1, 2]. It's all of the data in rows below that which are being duplicated. I will try to edit the post with an example of the data.

Comment: Delete `mode="a"` from your `to_csv`

Comment: @not_speshal if I remove mode="a" then I lose the first two rows that need to be there. I end up with only the header from row 3 and the non-duplicated data

Answer (score 1):

Try re-setting the columns of `nd` to the three-level header before `concat`:

```
data = pd.read_csv("file1.csv",sep="\t",header=[0,1,2])
nd = pd.read_csv("file2.csv",sep="\t")
nd.columns = data.columns

output = pd.concat([data,nd])
output.to_csv('file', sep='\t', index=False)

>>> output
  load        v1.0      74b  FlatFile
   ver        raid     week     month
  Dept        Date    Sales IsHoliday
0    1  2010-02-05  24924.5     False
0    3  2010-07-05   6743.5     False
```

Comment: This is so close to being right, however I need to select the columns from the 3rd row.  
data.columns selects the first row of headers is there a way to select a different row? ie. Dept, Date, Sales, IsHoliday

Comment: thanks for the answer, it set me on track to working it out!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better way of doing it but I've ended up with this result that works.

```
data = pd.read_csv('file', sep='\t', header=[0, 1, 2])
columns = data.columns

ndf = pd.DataFrame(data=nd, columns=data.columns.get_level_values(2))
data.columns = data.columns.get_level_values(2)
new_data = pd.concat([data, ndf])

new_data.columns = columns
new_data.to_csv('file', sep='\t', index=False, header=True)
```

So what I did was, set the ndf to have the same columns as the third row of data, then did the same data.
This allowed me to concat the two dataframes.
I still had the issue that I was missing the first 2 rows of headers but if I saved the columns from the original data file I could then asign the columns, back to the original values, before I saved to csv.